# Function docstrings not on the web/pdf api reference scipy.stats?

Tags: python, scipy

Am I misunderstanding how to use SciPy documentation?

I'm finding that I get much less-detailed information about stats.gamma.fit from [the SciPy API Reference webpage/pdf, at least for scipy.stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html#scipy.stats.gamma), than I do from doing `stats.gamma.fit?` on a python console. Particularly I was unable to find out how the return value is structured from the web/pdf API Reference, even though it describes itself as

> The exact API of all functions and classes, as given by the docstrings. The API documents expected types and allowed features for all functions, and all parameters available for the algorithms.

I also think there's a contradiction between the specification described by the web/pdf API Reference and the console docstring. Specifically, the web/pdf Reference says that the `fit` method produces a default value for the parameters `floc` and `fscale`. But the docstring from the console says,

> `kwds : floats, optional Starting values for the location and scale
>   parameters; no default.`

Am I reading these right?

Comment: This appears to be the detailed API for the `fit` method: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html.  The key is that `gamma` is a subclass of a more generic `rv_continuous`.  The methods are documented for the parent class, not each subclass.

Comment: @hpaulj: It's an instance, not a subclass. It'd probably inherit parent method docs if it was a subclass. (`numpy.matrix` inherits docs for a bunch of inherited methods from `numpy.ndarray`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, the method `fit` is documented within the [`rv_continuous` class](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html), specifically [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit). This documentation is not repeated for each instance of the class such as `gamma`.

> Starting values for the location and scale parameters; no default.

This is technically correct but in a somewhat misleading way. It means the `fit` method signature `fit(self, data, *args, **kwds)` does not include default values for any arguments; there is no `loc=0`, etc here.

Since some starting values are necessary for the minimizer to work, they will be generated by calling an internal method `_fitstart` if not provided by the user:

```
if (Narg < self.numargs) or not ('loc' in kwds and 'scale' in kwds):
    start = self._fitstart(data)
```

One can think of the values provided by `_fitstart` as default, but they are not default parameter values in the Python sense.